# What's the probability of guessing this problem and getting it right? (a) 20% (b) 30% (c) 25% (d) 20% (e) 50%

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The solution says its (e), since we have to guess (a) or (d) to get it right.(I know it doesn't makes any sense and I can't understand it)

Its quite similar to Russell's paradox and I could not find or think of a clear solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed paradoxical. The only way to escape it, assuming there is only one correct answer, would be the following: at each run of the test (that is, every time a new student answers the question), the correct answer is randomly selected to be either (a) or (d) with equal probability, and the remaining one is marked as incorrect. It would be the only alternative to simply accepting that the question has no answer.